# SQL Multiple GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out the mysql query to extract the data I want from this table "**timeEntry**":

```
hours     creationDate    userId    clientId    projectId    taskId
20        2012-02-18      1         1           1            1
40        2012-02-18      1         1           1            1
30        2012-02-21      2         1           1            1
20        2012-02-22      2         1           1            2
30        2012-02-22      2         1           1            2
80        2012-02-23      1         2           2            2
10        2012-02-23      3         2           2            2
15        2012-02-23      1         2           2            3
40        2012-02-23      1         2           4            1
```

And I would like to have this kind of result as another table, or csv/excel file or php array (where totalHours is the sum of the hours for a userId) for a given period of time, let say (between 2012-02-01 and 2012-02-25):

```
clientId    projectId    taskId    userId    totalHours
1           1            1         1         60
                                   2         30
                         2         2         50 
2           2            2         1         80 
                                   3         10
                         3         1         15
            4            1         1         40
```

I guess I have to use multiple group by, I tried something like:

```
SELECT clientId, projectId, taskId, userId, sum(hours)
FROM `timeEntry`
WHERE date_creation >= "2012-02-01"
AND date_creation <= "2012-02-25"
GROUP BY  clientId, projectId, taskId, userId;
```

But didn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide schema on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Do you really want no data in sub rows?  For example for your second and third rows would it be OK if they had a value of `1` for `clientId`?

Comment: @Abe Miessler : yes it would totally be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where needs to go before Group by.

If you want to filter by date before grouping, use the where clause you have but moved before the group by.

If you'd instead like to filter entire groups in or out, use a having:

```
...
Group by ...
Having max(date) <= someValue and min(date) >= someValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT clientId, projectId, taskId, userId    sum(Hours) total_hours 
FROM timeEntry 
GROUP BY clientID, ProjectID, TaskID, userID;
```

You can use `[with Rollup][1]` to generate sub-aggregrates. if you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. You need to group by all necessary fields

```
SELECT
  t.clientId,
  t.projectId,
  t.taskId,
  t.userId,
  SUM(t.hours) AS Total
FROM test AS t
GROUP BY t.creationDate , t.userId , t.clientId , t.projectId , t.taskId
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc072/1)

OUTPUT:

```
clientId    projectId   taskId  userId   Total
____________________________________________________________

    1           1           1       1       60
    1           1           1       2       30
    1           1           2       2       50
    2           2           2       1       80
    2           2           3       1       15
    2           4           1       1       40
    2           2           2       3       10
```